# filter wordpress comment with custom field befor load

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

Hello everyone and thank you for your help:

How can I filter the comments displayed under a page befor load based on a custom field? For example, if the custom field has a value of a, that comment should be displayed, and if it does not have this value, it should not be displayed.

i use this sample code:

$comments20 = get_comments (array ('meta_key'=> 'keytoopurl', 'meta_value'=> 'y'));

The number of comments is very high and I want WordPress to receive only comments with high conditions before receiving comments. I also used the example code below but it does not work:

```
add_action('pre_get_comments', function ($queryObj) {
            $vars = $queryObj->query_vars;
            $vars['meta_key'] = 'keytoopurl';
            $vars['meta_value'] = 'y';
            $queryObj->query_vars = $vars;
    });
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. I am posting content for others to use.
plugin wpdiscuz caches comments, which is why our code does not work. Also, after writing the filter, it is necessary to activate and deactivate the plugin once. The problem was solved by adding the following line of code.

```
add_action('pre_get_comments', function ($query)
{
    $query->query_vars['meta_query'] = [
        [
            'key' => 'keyurl',
            'value' => "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"
        ]
    ];
}, 10, 1);
```

If you used this article, please like my answer